Exclude CMS Items from Custom Attribute Filtering in Webflow
I am working on a Webflow site. We have a CMS collection of TV Channels that are grouped by package. On the TV Channels page, the packages each have their own buttons where customers can see which channels belong to which packages. Those buttons use the Custom Attribute Filter "filter-by=package name" to display which channels belong to which package.
The issue I'm facing is that the package name "Discover" also displays all channels that have the word "Discover" in their title. For example, the "Discover" package should not display the channel named "Discovery Velocity". Is there a way to exclude certain CMS items when using this filtering method?
I tried adding the custom attribute "exclude-cms-items=channel name" but that did nothing.
